# CAN - duplicate message at receiver possibilities?

Tags: microcontroller, can

This Link says a that :[Use of sequence numbers fixes the duplicate error](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee249/fa07/CANBus.pdf).

When can duplicate message end up at a receiver?

If a node detects an error, it sends out an error flag and when all the other receiving nodes detect the error, they too send out error flags and destroy the received message. The transmitter then resends the message again.

Im not aware of the possibilities of a duplicate messages being received...

Plz Help as i must decide if sequence number must be used or not in my messages.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The presentation you linked to talks about a situation where a receiver accepts a message, but a transmitter recognizes the same message as incorrectly transmitted. Currently I don't understand exactly how that would happen, but I guess a receiver could use data from a frame where the ACK bit does not get set for any reason, which causes the transmitter to resend the frame.

IMO the exact reason why this can or would happen is irrelevant, but instead you have to think about the kind of data that you are transmitting: if you periodically send e.g. the current value of a sensor reading over the bus a retransmission will not be a bad thing. If on the other hand your message contains a small chunk of a larger data block then resending that part will cause the larger block to be corrupt. This is the reason why protocols like CCP or XCP contain a message counter.

Comment: "a transmitter recognizes the same message as incorrectly transmitted" I suppose this could be caused by noise on the Rx line, between the CAN transceiver and the MCU? Those signals are not differential, and plain TTL levels. So given a poor PCB design, it is quite possible you could get problems with them, especially at higher baud rates.

Comment: The truth is, if your CAN nodes receive messages inconsistently, the whole system is broken. Message counters won't help, you'll have to fix the bus if you want it to work. The reason why XCP has a message counter is because it supports unreliable transmission media such as Ethernet.

Comment: @0x6d64- Yes il be sending data in packets(big block in small chunks).

Comment: @Lundin- Ur situation seems possible. A transmitter sends a message, the receivers receive the msg with no errors but the ACK flag at the transmitter end doesnt become dominant and stays recessive due to noise/failure of the RX pin between the Tranceiver and MCU. This will cause the transmitter to resend the message & increase transmit error counter(upto 127 before going to error passive). But when the transmitter sends out an error flag(when in error active), wont the receivers destroy the received message?

Comment: @0x6d64- Yes il be sending huge data fragmented into smaller packets.

Comment: @AkshayImmanuelD: then I think you should include a message counter or another method to check the whole sum (like a checksum over the data block after it got recombined on the receiver).

Comment: @0x6d64- Yes il use message counters. 2 bytes for command,2 bytes for sequence number/message counters(Split into 1 byte for Packet Number,1 byte for Total packets). Then at the receiver end i can use a dispatch table to index the command and place it in an array,where the received msg counter is the array location. If packet number received matches the total packets,set a flag to indicate that the entire msg has been received

Answer (score 0):

Possibility 1:

The point of time at which a message is taken to be valid, is different for the transmitter
and the receivers of the message. The transmitter checks all bits until the end of
END OF FRAME field. Receivers consider a message valid if there is no error until the
last but one bit of END OF FRAME. The value of the last bit of END OF FRAME is
treated as dont care, (a dominant value does not lead to a FORM ERROR). This difference
in the interpretation of a valid transmission/reception of a message can give rise
to inconsistent message omissions/duplicates.
If a transmitter detects that the last bit is a dominant instead of a recessive,it will resend. The receiver has no clue that this is a duplicate message because it did not consider the previous message as an error.

[Reference for the answer](http://inst.cs.berkeley.edu/~ee249/fa08/Lectures/handout_canbus2.pdf)

[Overload frame conditions](http://www.can-cia.org/can-knowledge/can/can-data-link-layers/)

Comment: But now that the transmitter knows that its an error, does it retransmit the message with no error flag? Or does it send an error flag and then retransmit? If it sends an error flag and then retransmits, when the receivers detect an error flag sent by the transmitter, wont they destroy the previously received messages??? So again, duplicate messages wont be received at the nodes.. Still confused about the answer i posted as the link does not talk about this scenario i have mentioned. Plz help